# Correct way to use reference lvalues

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue, ampersand

My code is the following:

```
void parentheses (int n, string& str, int left, int right){

    ... irrelevant... 

}
void solve(int n){
    parentheses(n,"",0,0);
}
```

However, this will give me an error, telling me that `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type std::__cxx11::string& ... to an rvalue of type ‘std::__cxx11::string`. In this case, if I still want to pass the string in as a reference, how should I modify my functions? I don't want to make them `const` because I want to functions to modify the original string, and I want them to be `&` precisely because I want to edit their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function *parentheses* expects an lvalue in the std::string parameter, i.e. a named variable. However, you have supplied an rvalue (temporary) in this call:

parentheses(n,"",0,0);

An empty string object is created and passed to parentheses. You can avoid this problem by changing the definition of parentheses like so:

```
void parentheses (int n, const string& str, int left, int right)
```

Here str will bind to an rvalue/temporary, but you won't be able to change its value in the function. However, if you want to change the value of str you have to define a string variable and pass that to the function.

Example:

```
void solve(int n){
    std::string str;
    parentheses(n,str,0,0);
}
```

Note: no need to assign str to "" as a string is empty by default.

Answer (score 2):

the function needs a memory to change, you didn't specify which.
declare a string to hold what you want to pass and where to get the output to.

```
string s = "";
```

and pass it to the function

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what the purpose is of passing `""` by reference is, as any value put there will get lost.

Anyway, to answer your question, create a variable and pass it instead:

```
void solve(int n){
    std::string tmp = "";
    parentheses(n,tmp,0,0);
}
```

If you don't care about the value stored in `tmp`, you can just ignore it. But you need *some* type of variable there, even if you don't care about what gets eventually put there by the routine.

Answer (score 2):

Your `parentheses()` function takes a **non-const reference** to a `std::string` object, so it expects an actual `std::string` object on the other side of the reference - an lvalue (something that can be assigned to).

But your `solve()` function is not passing a `std::string` object, it is passing a string literal instead. So the compiler creates a *temporary* `std::string` object - an rvalue - which then fails to bind to the reference, because a temporary object can't be bound to a *non-const* reference, only to a *const* reference. That is what the error message is telling you:

> cannot bind **non-const lvalue reference** of type std::__cxx11::string& ... to an **rvalue** of type ‘std::__cxx11::string

`solve()` needs to explicitly create an actual `std::string` object to pass to `parentheses()`:

```cpp
void solve(int n){
    std::string s = "";
    parentheses(n,s,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the values of your string for any string that is passed as a paramenter (lvalue, as well rvalue), just initialize a variable with the intended content and pass it to your function.

But if you want to treat lvalue strings diferently from rvalue strings, just overload your original function. i.e.:

```
void parentheses (int n, string& str, int left, int right){
    ... irrelevant... // change strings values as desired
}

void parentheses (int n, string&& str, int left, int right){
    ... irrelevant... // string as rvalue
}
```